# Can find out why laravel tries to run apt-get in mac os

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am very new to Laravel and I have been assigned to work on a laravel app.

I installed composer and when i do composer install or composer update i see this in the terminal:

```
> php artisan optimize
  Generating optimized class loader
> php artisan test:setup
  sudo apt-get install -y xvfb firefox chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver
  Password:
```

I don't understand why it is running that command on my mac? How can i disable that?

Comment: that's not "ubuntu", `apt` is from Debian, and is the package manager for any Debian-derived Linux distro, including ubuntu.

Comment: I am not asking what command it is. I am asking how not to have it run when i do the install or update.

Comment: which is why that was a comment, to correct your terminology, and not an answer to your question.

Comment: Ok I will update, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running an artisan command `test:setup`. As far as i know that is not a standard laravel artisan command.

Someone in that project probably made a custom command in the `app/commands` folder that installs those packages for you so you are able to run certain custom tests.

If you want to remove it:
Look inside the `app/commands` or search your project for a file like `testCommand.php` and disable the code.

You can read more about [artisan commands in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands).

Comment: Good answer. Given the packages it's trying to install, I'll bet `test:setup` tries to setup a JavaScript test runner for front-end testing.